# Jekyll kramdown math render settings

Tags: ruby, jekyll, kramdown, katex

I recently updated to Jekyll 4.0.1 I have made plugin which detects and render latex expressions to html using katex. But now Jekyll's kramdown renders latex expressions differently.

In old jekyll would render `$$ 1 + 1 = 2$$` like this:

```
<script type="math\/tex; mode=display">1 + 1 = 2<\/script>
```

now it is rendered as:

```
/[ 1 + 1 = 2 /]
```

How can I set kramdown to render the old way ?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution is to set math engine to katex**

---

First you need to install katex gem:

```sh
sudo gem install kramdown-math-katex
```

and then add kramdown option to jekyll config file:

```yaml
kramdown:
    math-engine: katex
```